# iam permission required to read table metadata from information schema

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-iam

I am new in GCP and I came across one requirement. I want to compare DDLs of the table in dev and production environment but I don't have production access. I want to run below query's,

```
select table_name   FROM  `my-project`.my_prod_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
select table_name   FROM  `my-project`.my_prod_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

now I don't have any acess in prod db so not able to run these. I found that to run above queries I need to have bigquery.metadataViewer role but I also want to know is there any specific permission within this role which I can ask ? as getting prod access is very difficult and I just want permission to run above 2 queries. can any one help here to know the exact permission required to run above queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required permissions are listed

[here for TABLES](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#required_permissions):

> bigquery.tables.get 
> bigquery.tables.list 
> bigquery.routines.get 
> bigquery.routines.list

and [here for COLUMNS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-columns#required_permissions):

> bigquery.tables.get 
> bigquery.tables.list

Comment: Thankq so much @dnnshssm, just Curious to know why these two are required if i want table and column details ,     bigquery.routines.get
bigquery.routines.list